# Как вставить картинку в RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как вставить картинку в RichTextBox? Находил нормальный пример только на WPF, а мне нужно на WinForms. У меня текст в RichTextBox записывается с файла, и в некоторых местах текста нужно вставить определенную картинку. Мне нужно программно вставлять изображение с файла. Как это можно сделать? И есть ли какой-то годный аналог RichTextBox?

Comment: Через буфер обмена?

Comment: Нет. Мне нужно программно вставлять изображение с файла.

Comment: Можно и програмно работать с буфером обмена.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужно модифицировать код RTF. Изображения в RTF представляются в следующем формате:

> "{\pict\wmetafile8\picw[N]\pich[N]\picwgoal[N]\pichgoal[N] [BYTES]}",
>   где
>
> \pict - группа изображения
>
> \wmetafile[N] - индикатор того, что изображение является Windows
>   Metafile. [N] = 8 указывает, что размеры осей метафайла могут быть
>   изменены независимо.
>
> \picw[N] и \pich[N] - указывает размер изображения, где [N]
>   указывается в сотых миллиметра (0.01мм).
>
> \picwgoal[N] и \pichgoal[N]   - указывает желаемый размер изображения,
>   где [N] указыается в 1/1440 дюйма.
>
> [BYTES]   - HEX-представление изображения.

Почитать о том, как правильно реализовать модифицию RTF-кода, можно тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017044/insert-image-at-cursor-position-in-rich-text-box

Answer (score 7):

Можно попробовать вставить картинку, используя метод `Paste()`:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("winter.jpg");
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetImage(img);
richTextBox1.Paste();
Clipboard.Clear();
```

Comment: А если у пользователя что-то было в клипборде, то это его проблема?

Comment: Ну можно каждый раз перед вставкой картинки сохранять буфер.